# What Did I Miss in Input Process?

Tags: go, input, user-input, time-limiting

I am solving a problem in Hackerearth. Passed all the test cases except 1, showing "***Time limit exceeded***". What did I really miss in my code?

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func rotateRight(numbers []int, size int, k int) []int {
    new_numbers := make([]int, size)
    for index, value := range numbers {
        new_numbers[(index + k) % size] = value
    }

    return new_numbers
}

func main() {
    var test_case, size, k int

    fmt.Scanf("%v", &test_case)
    fmt.Scanln()
    for i := 0; i < test_case; i++ {
        fmt.Scanf("%v %v", &size, &k)
        fmt.Scanln()
        
        numbers := make([]int, size)
        for i := 0; i<size; i++ {
            fmt.Scanf("%v", &numbers[i])
        }

        result := rotateRight(numbers, size, k)

        fmt.Println(strings.Trim(fmt.Sprint(result), "[]"))
    }
}
```

Comment: [Benchmarks](https://pkg.go.dev/testing#hdr-Benchmarks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe the reason is the way that you read the data, fmt is really slow, try change it with

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    sc := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    sc.Scan()
    sc.Text()//here you have your data
}
```

this change will improve the time wasted